# Single usage VkImageMemoryBarrier?

Tags: vulkan

I've been learning vulkan and following vulkan-tutorial and right now I'm at the [Texture mapping](https://vulkan-tutorial.com/Texture_mapping/Images) part. I'm loading an image and uploading it to the host memory, but I'm having trouble understanding the layout transitions and barriers.

Consider this (pseudo)code for loading and transitioning an image (inspired by [this](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/wiki/Synchronization-Examples-(Legacy-synchronization-APIs)#upload-data-from-the-cpu-to-an-image-sampled-in-a-fragment-shader)), which will be sampled in a fragment shader:

```
auto texture = loadTexture(filePath);
auto stagingBuffer = createStagingBuffer(texture.pixels, texture.size);

// Create image with: 
//   usage - VK_IMAGE_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_SAMPLED_BIT
//   properties - VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT
auto imageBuffer = createImage();

// -- begin single usage command buffer --
auto cb = beginCommandBuffer();

VkImageMemoryBarrier preCopyBarrier {
    // ...
    .image = imageBuffer.image,
    .srcAccessMask = 0,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
    .oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
    .newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
    // ...
};

// PipelineBarrier (preCopyBarrier):
//   srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TOP_OF_PIPE_BIT
//   dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT
//   imageMemoryBarrier = &preCopyBarrier
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cb, ...);

// Copy stagingBuffer.buffer to imageBuffer.image
//   dstImageLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL
vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(cb, ...);

VkImageMemoryBarrier postCopyBarrier {
    // ...
    .image = imageBuffer.image,
    .srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_WRITE_BIT,
    .dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,
    .oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL,
    .newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,
    // ...
};

// PipelineBarrier (postCopyBarrier):
//   srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT
//   dstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT
//   imageMemoryBarrier = &postCopyBarrier
vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cb, ...)

endAndSubmitCommandBuffer(cb);
```

The `preCopyBarrier` is there because of the `vkCmdCopyBufferToImage(...)` command and will be "used"/"activated" only once and that is during this command(?).

The `postCopyBarrier` is there because of the fact, that it will be sampled in the fragment shader, so the layout transition

`VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSFER_DST_OPTIMAL -> VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL`

has to happen every single time a frame is rendered(? Please correct me, if I'm wrong).

But (assuming I'm correct, which I'm probably not) I'm having trouble wrapping my head around the fact, that I'm creating a `preCopyBarrier`, which will be used only once and `postCopyBarrier`, which will be used continuously. If I were to load for example 200 textures, I'd have a bunch of their single usage `preCopyBarrier`s laying around. Isn't this a...waste?

This might be a stupid question and I'm probably missing/misunderstanding something important, but I feel like I shouldn't move on without understanding this concept correctly.

Comment: Seems only like a simple one-off command buffer that is executed only once to initialize the images to a defined and expected state. Since this code load from file, I assume nothing here is executed every single frame.

Comment: @krOoze I see.. That would actually make much more sense. For some reason I thought, that the image can't stay in the ```VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL``` layout, so I assumed, that ```vkCmdPipelineBarrier(...)``` somehow creates this barrier forever - and from that point on I went completely off track... Thank you